# Sharepoint: document remains check out after it is uploaded

Tags: sharepoint, checkout, checkin

I am uploading document using Copy Services into document library, after that setting libraries required fields too but document still remains checked out for that user. I have also checked version settings for that library. Did not help anything.! Is there anything that i am missing?

Comment: Does it have all the required fields filled out? do you have checking logic in your code? also once uploaded did you try checkin manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though i was filling all the required fields, document remained checked out. **So simply changing all required fields to optional fixed the problem.**